# Fonts displaying incorrectly

Tags: 18.04, fonts

It's easier to describe my problem with some pictures.
Some letters are displayed wrong, randomly. This problem doesn't appear in browser, console, just in system applications, I guess. Also, I tried installing Kali linux and the problem wasn't solved.

I tried changing font hinting in gnome-tweaks, no result. Just some letters became normal, but most of them are displayed wrong as in picture below.

[image: problem pic]

Oh, and here is my neofetch output:

```
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS x86_64
Host: SQ45/Q70C/P200 04SO
Kernel: 4.18.0-16-generic
Packages: 1637
Shell: bash 4.4.19
Resolution: 1280x800
DE: GNOME 3.28.3
WM: GNOME Shell
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Ambiance [GTK2/3]
Icons: Ubuntu-mono-dark [GTK2/3]
Terminal: gnome-terminal
CPU: Intel Pentium Dual T2390 (2) @
GPU: AMD Radeon Xpress 1250
Memory: 1049Mib /1740Mib
```

Any ideas how to deal with this?

upd: I tried installing Xubuntu, no font problems there. I think the problem is in lack of RAM memory. XFCe desktop used in Xubuntu requires less RAM than GNOME, I suppose. Nevertheless, can the problem be solved?

Comment: Are you using the `radeon` driver that comes built into the kernel? Do `dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'` to see if there are any problems with that.

Comment: [output of dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'](https://imgur.com/MedZKLU) @Jos doesn't look like there any problems with it. at least for me

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Instead copy & paste the text here and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help). Also always [edit] your question and add important info. Comments may get overlooked easily.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to not use usual GNOME3 shell. Seems like the problem is in lack of RAM, that's why I switched to lxqt, where everything worked. Also, I tried switching to Cinnamon, but the problem wasn't solved. The only answer to give is to get more RAM if you're using a PC, or to switch desktop environment if you're using a laptop.